# Insufficient Privileges Error for a particular picklist value

Tags: visualforce, permission-sets

I am getting this error while saving saving a record with a particular picklist value .

1. It is a VF Page
2. User is accessing through a permission set.
3. There is no restriction of picklist value through Record Type
4. permission has been given to all the fields in the vf page.
5. object concerned is in a master detail relationship.
6. no restriction of value through apex.

What else do I need to check?

Comment: Check field level Security for Picklist.

Comment: @abdn-Yes checked. Field is visible . I guess you cannot restrict values through FLS . There is no restriction through any Record Type.